# Angular. Generate directive inside directive. Where is my scope stuff?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to generate multiple `expressionSelect` directives inside my `expressionAuthoring` directive, in this case, on a simple click. I can get the `expressionSelect` template to appear, but with none of my scope stuff will come with it. I have searched and seen various examples/similar concerns, but none of which I was able to directly pull the solution from and get my own to work. Ideas?

**I am not using a controller outside what is shown here**

```
app.directive('expressionAuthoring', ['$compile', function (compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind('click', function () {
                var selection = angular.element(document.createElement('expression-select'));
                var el = compile(selection)(scope);
                element.append(el);
            });
        }
    };
}]);

app.directive('expressionSelect', [ function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<select ng-model="expressionSelect" ng-options="e.name for e in expressionSelect"></select>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.expressionSelect = [
                { name: 'TestName1', value: 'TestValue1' },
                { name: 'TestName2', value: 'TestValue2' },
                { name: 'TestName3', value: 'TestValue3' }
            ];
        }
    };
}]);
```

When I simply place the `<expression-select></expression-select>` somewhere in my html
[image]

---

When I generate it in my 'parent' directive

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is curious, I was able to get this working by adding `scope.$apply();`

```
element.bind('click', function () {
    var selection = angular.element(document.createElement('expression-select'));
    var el = compile(selection)(scope);
    scope.$apply();
    element.append(el);
});
```